# mid3v2 Error on Attempt to Set Picture Tag

Tags: linux, mp3, id3

When trying to set picture tag for MP3 file using mid3v2, I get the following error message:

```
mid3v2 [OPTION] [FILE]...
mid3v2: error: no such option: --picture
```

Yet, the documentation states this is a valid option. Any ideas on what the problem may be?

I'm using mid3v2 1.3 which uses Mutagen 1.31. The command is:

```
mid3v2 --song "Song Title" --album "Album Name" --year "2020" --artist "Artist Name" --track "1" --picture "/images/106.jpg" "/mnt/cifs/Radio Programming/Programs/pp212.mp3"
```

If I leave out the --picture option, tag gets written.

Regards,
Anthony

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could you edit your question to show the exact command that resulted in this error? Also, please indicate which version of `mid3v2` you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the mutagen changelog](https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html#id22), APIC support was added to mid3v2 for version 1.33, which was released on 29th June 2016. ([mutagen version 1.31 was released on 9th Sept 2015](https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html#id24))